# Internet Explorer 10 - (Javascript or jQuery) How to change attributes and property without knowing which type it is (dynamic changes)?

Tags: javascript, properties, attributes, internet-explorer-10, setattribute

Please bear with the pseudocode and formatting, I can't really remember the code off the top of my head.

In IE9 and below, I know you could set properties and attributes by using the setAttribute() method, but that seems to have been changed in IE10 by a separating attributes and properties separately.

Even doing something like

```
element.setAttribute("className", "myClass");
```

sets the element to appear as

```
<tag className = "myClass" />
```

which doesn't even set the property.

In my code, I have a JSON list that I use to store the names and values of the attributes/properties, which I simply set with setAttribute();

```
createElement(tag, list)
{
    //pseudocode
    var element = createElementWithTag(tag);
    for each(attr in attributes)
       if (attributes.hasOwnKey(attr))
           element.setAttribute(attr, attributes[attr]);
}
```

And this worked fine for IE7-9, but completely fails in IE10.

Is there some way that I can set the property and attribute without which type (attr or prop) it is?

I can't even think of a way to set the property dynamically, without hardcoding a case for which property I want to change.

A solution would probably also be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think something like this is what you want:

```
function tag(tag, attribs) {
    if(tag.charAt) tag = document.createElement(tag);
    var alias = {
        htmlFor: "for",
        className: "class"
    }, prop;
    for (prop in attribs) if (attribs.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        if("style" == prop) tag.style.cssText = attribs[prop];
        try {
            tag[prop] = attribs[prop];
        } catch (h) {
            tag.setAttribute( alias[prop] || prop, attribs[prop]);
        }
    }
    return tag;
}


//test it:
tag("a", {href:"/", target:"_blank", innerHTML:" some text ", className: "1 2 3"}).outerHTML
```

tested in IE8 and Chrome.

if anyone knows of more dom->attrib mappings (like htmlFor), please edit them into the answer, thanks!

Comment: It worked, thanks a bunch!  I would upvote if I had enough reputation...  I'm a little wary of try catch blocks since they slow things down, and even though it probably wouldn't matter much on a small web page, I decided to do this:      if(tag[prop !== "undefined") tag[prop] = attribs[prop] else tag.setAttribute[prop, attribs[prop]);    Not sure if that's a better implementation though...

Comment: Also, can you explain why you used tag.setAttribute(alias[prop] || prop, attribs[prop]) instead of just tag.setAttribute[prop, attribs[prop]);?

Comment: @MaskedTwilight: your if statement will always be true, take off the quotes around undefined. the only thing tried is setting a property, which is very quick and can afford to be slowed down without impact. if you use it strictly, you can get away with removing it. the try is to stop exceptions on weird tags like embed and when setting certain properties in IE that don't like to be set. the alias is needed to translate "className" into "class" for the setAttribute call. it homogenizes between attrib names and property names.